# Castle Windsor: Registering Multiple Types

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, design-patterns, castle

Assuming I have several classes that implement an interface: IFileDownloader.

If I register a component individually everything is fine:

```
kernel.Register(Component.For<IFileDownloader>().ImplementedBy<HttpFileDownloader>());
```

However if I try and register all components that implement that interface it does't seem to register them:

```
kernel.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IFileDownloader>());
```

I must be missing something obvious.

Many Thanks,
-Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be two reasons why your registration is not working as you expected

1. Your classes are internal and Windsor ignores them.
2. You didn't specify that you want to register them with `IFileDownloader` service. I think what you're after is:

   ```
   kernel.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
     .BasedOn<IFileDownloader>()
     .WithService.Base());
   ```

Comment: +1 Great that you finally dropped by... I knew there was something I'd forgotten :)

Comment: Can you advice me how to do it in a configuration file, please?

Comment: OOTB you can't. configuration file is for configuration, not for bootstrapping your entire application.